# Flex-iframe: problems in FF

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, firefox, iframe

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/ for showing wikicontent in a flex app.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:TitleWindow
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
xmlns:components="components.*"
title="Hjälp"
showCloseButton="true"
close="close();"
styleName="Popup"
paddingBottom="0"
paddingLeft="0"
paddingRight="0"
paddingTop="0"
width="700"
height="500">

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import mx.core.Application;
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

import offerta.Config;
import offerta.monkeywrench.Icons;
import offerta.utils.printf;

import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

private static var _popup:HelpPopup = null;

[Bindable]
public var callback:Function;

[Bindable]
public var key:String;

private function close(cancel:Boolean = true):void
{
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
    if(callback!=null) callback();
}

public static function create():HelpPopup
{
    HelpPopup._popup =
HelpPopup(PopUpManager.createPopUp(DisplayObject(Application.application),
HelpPopup, true));
    HelpPopup._popup.visible = false;
    return HelpPopup._popup;
}

public function show():void
{
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(HelpPopup._popup);
    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(function():void {
        refresh();
    },500);
}

public function refresh():void
{
    if(!!key)
    {
        frameMain.label = key;
        frameMain.source = printf(Config.DOCUMENTATION_URL,key);
    }
}

]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0"
paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0">

  <mx:ApplicationControlBar width="100%">

        <mx:HBox width="100%" id="pnlToolbar" horizontalGap="0">

            <mx:LinkButton
                  icon="{Icons.refresh}"
                  click="refresh();"/>

            <mx:LinkButton
                  icon="{Icons.previous}"
                  click="frameMain.historyBack()"/>

            <mx:LinkButton
                  icon="{Icons.next}"
                  click="frameMain.historyForward()"/>

        </mx:HBox>

    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <components:IFrame id="frameMain"
        loadIndicatorClass="components.IFrameLoadingIndicator"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"/>

</mx:VBox>

<mx:ControlBar>

    <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>

    <mx:Button
            width="80"
            height="30"
            label="Stäng"
            click="close();"/>

</mx:ControlBar>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

When displaying the window: In Ie. it works perfectly, but in FF the
content flashes quickly and then the iframe becomes blank?

Comment: Hi Niels, I see you posted this as a bug on the project site on the same day you posted it here.  They have an outstanding request to you on Oct 22 that you have not compelted.  They need you to provide a FlexBuilder 3 project showing the bug.  It appears they are not able to reproduce it and are looking for your help to fix it.  

If the developers of the code can't provide the details you need on there site I doubt you will get a response here that will work.

Comment: True and it's on my todo list. (I just don't have Flex builder 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed to add wmode=opaque and it works in FF. Only problem is that flex loadingindicator isn't showing.

Answer (score 2):

I answered you on the bug you opened on the project site ;)